# how can i read a certain block from a file in java?

Tags: java, block

My project description says that given a block number ex. first block , second block... i should read that block from the file. any ideas how to explicitly read a certain block from a file given the block number (int)? thankyou

Comment: Have you given https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html a read? That might be a good place to start.

Comment: What is a block in your file?

Comment: @FrankPuffer A block in my file is 4096 bytes

Comment: Ok, just wanted to make sure we are talking about binary random access files. Then I also recommend that you check out the link posted by @yshavit.